# Is there a way to filter a list with multiple input checkboxes? CSS and HTML Only

Tags: html, css, filtering

I'm trying to create a list of items that filter when one or more filter checkboxes are selected.

EX:
I have an A filter, B filter, C filter

My list is :
A
B
C

When I select the A, I want only the A to remain visible on the list, when I select B I want just the B to show, etc.

Likewise, if I select A and B (not C) I want both A and B values to show up, and even further, if I had a value that was AB, it should only show when both A and B are selected.

I need to be able to do this only with CSS and HTML because the internal corporate wiki page where I'm building this does not allow the "script" tag.

Looking around I've landed here so far, which works as expected, only showing the below items when the corresponding filter is selected:

CSS:

```css
input[name=a]:checked~.items div:not([data-type=a]),
input[name=b]:checked~.items div:not([data-type=b]),
input[name=c]:checked~.items div:not([data-type=c]) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="a" style="display: inline-block;"> A
<br/><input type="checkbox" name="b" style="display: inline-block;"> B
<br/><input type="checkbox" name="c" style="display: inline-block;"> C
<hr/>
<div class="items">
  <div data-type="a">A</div>
  <div data-type="b">B</div>
  <div data-type="c">C</div>
</div>
```

When I try to include logic in the CSS for multi select, I'm getting stuck. I added this line which specifies that when both A and B are checked, I want both A and B values to show, but how I wrote it below isn't working and I'm not sure how to move forward (specifically, how to I specify both data types a and b in this line below

```
(`input[name=a]:checked + input[name=b]:checked ~ .items div:not([data-type=a, b]){
  display: none;
}`:
```

CSS

```
input[name=a]:checked ~ .items div:not([data-type=a]),
input[name=b]:checked ~ .items div:not([data-type=b]),
input[name=c]:checked ~ .items div:not([data-type=c]),
input[name=a]:checked + input[name=b]:checked ~ .items div:not([data-type=a, b]){
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: The + sign in CSS isn't used for logic, it's called the adjacent sibling selector. Therefore ".a + .b" means "select the b class which is right after an a class".

Comment: You should get in the habit of using an element to label form elements, especially checkboxes. Turns out, there's one purpose-built for it! `<label>`! Then, people can click on both the form element or the label to check the box, giving them an increased chance of hitting the mark. It also helps people with accessibility issues understand and use the form, so bonus points there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps just change your logic around to checked = show that one and hide them by default.

```css
.items>[data-type] {
  display: none;
}

input[name=a]:checked~.items div[data-type=a],
input[name=b]:checked~.items div[data-type=b],
input[name=c]:checked~.items div[data-type=c] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="a" style="display: inline-block;"> A
<br/><input type="checkbox" name="b" style="display: inline-block;"> B
<br/><input type="checkbox" name="c" style="display: inline-block;"> C
<hr/>
<div class="items">
  <div data-type="a">A</div>
  <div data-type="b">B</div>
  <div data-type="c">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Much cleaner and makes much more sense. 

Let's say we added a 4th value which was AB, As a continuation, What would you need to add to so that "AB" only showed up when both A and B are selected?

Comment: @AndrewPhillips `... div[data-type*=a]` and so on

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you!! And a follow up, what if I want AB to only show when inputs a & input b are selected. Your solution shows AB when just a or just b are selected, as well as a & b, but I want AB to only show when both A and B are selected and not otherwise.

Comment: Looking for a unique 4th value to appear only when all 3 checkboxes are selected.

Comment: That is a new question; perhaps ask a new one with that specific requirement

Comment: Thanks @MarkSchultheiss added here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77217036/filter-a-list-based-on-multiple-checked-checkboxes-with-only-css-html