# Filter a list based on multiple checked checkboxes with ONLY CSS & HTML

Tags: html, css, filter

I'm trying to create a filterable list of items that shows unique values when a combination of filters are checked. I need to be able to do this **with only with CSS and HTML** because the internal corporate wiki page where I'm building this does not allow the "script" tag.

My list is : A B C

My Values are A, B, C, D

I want value A to show when just filter A is checked, value B to show when just filter B is selected, and so on.

**I want value D to show only when filters A, B & C are all checked.**

This is what I currently have:

```css
.items>[data-type] {
  display: none;
}

input[name=a]:checked~.items div[data-type=a],
input[name=b]:checked~.items div[data-type=b],
input[name=c]:checked~.items div[data-type=c] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="a" style="display: inline-block;"> A
<br/><input type="checkbox" name="b" style="display: inline-block;"> B
<br/><input type="checkbox" name="c" style="display: inline-block;"> C
<hr/>
<div class="items">
  <div data-type="a">A</div>
  <div data-type="b">B</div>
  <div data-type="c">C</div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to specify with the CSS that **data-type=d** is the result of input a, b, and c being checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh damn, it's doable...

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label {
  padding-left: .2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]~label::after {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
}

.items>[data-type] {
  display: none;
}

input#a:checked ~ .items div[data-type=a],
input#b:checked ~ .items div[data-type=b],
input#c:checked ~ .items div[data-type=c],
input#a:checked ~ input#b:checked ~ input#c:checked ~ .items div[data-type=d] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="a"><label for="a"> A </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="b"><label for="b"> B </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="c"><label for="c"> C </label>

<hr>

<div class="items">
  <div data-type="a">A</div>
  <div data-type="b">B</div>
  <div data-type="c">C</div>
  <div data-type="d">D</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were in the right way

```css
.items>[data-type] {
  display: none;
}

input[name=a]:checked~.items div[data-type=a],
input[name=b]:checked~.items div[data-type=b],
input[name=c]:checked~.items div[data-type=c] {
  display: block;
}

/* Sequential siblings check */
input[name=a]:checked~input[name=b]:checked~input[name=c]:checked~.items div[data-type=d] {
  display: block;
}

/* Update: Hide everything else */
input[name=a]:checked~input[name=b]:checked~input[name=c]:checked~.items div[data-type=a],
input[name=a]:checked~input[name=b]:checked~input[name=c]:checked~.items div[data-type=b],
input[name=a]:checked~input[name=b]:checked~input[name=c]:checked~.items div[data-type=c]{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
    <input type="checkbox" name="a" style="display: inline-block;"> A
<br><input type="checkbox" name="b" style="display: inline-block;"> B
<br><input type="checkbox" name="c" style="display: inline-block;"> C
<hr>
<div class="items">
  <div data-type="a">A</div>
  <div data-type="b">B</div>
  <div data-type="c">C</div>
  <div data-type="d">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! Super helpful!!! The one other piece to this is how would you then hide A,B,C when D is selected, as D represents the combination of ABC checked, I don't want ABC to still be visible when D is showing.

Comment: You combine the sequential siblings check to hide the ABC answers... Let me update my answer

Comment: @andrew-phillips I'm guessing that's what you're looking for?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a verbose version.  Pretty verbose and ugly.  Starting to get a bit MUCH when we do a show/hide of AB, BC, ABC etc. I did not take time to dive deep but there might be a simpler method using just CSS - or just enlist JavaScript to do some of this.

Here is a verbose set of notes:

Since this is a cascade (C in **c**ss) we go top/down

Format the `label` with a left pad between it and the checkbox:

```
input[type="checkbox"]~label {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

Format the `label` with a new line after:

```
input[type="checkbox"]~label::after {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
  margin-left: 3em;
}
```

Hide them all initially:

```
.items>[data-type] {
  display: none;
}
```

Now show the single checked target:

```
input[name=a]:checked~.items div[data-type=a],
input[name=b]:checked~.items div[data-type=b],
input[name=c]:checked~.items div[data-type=c] {
  display: block;
}
```

Now when there are TWO (or three) checked we target that ones siblings:

```
input:is(input[name=a]:checked ~ input[name=b]:checked)~.items div[data-type=d],
input:is(input[name=a]:checked ~ input[name=c]:checked)~.items div[data-type=e],
input:is(input[name=b]:checked ~ input[name=c]:checked)~.items div[data-type=f],
input:is(input[name=a]:checked ~ input[name=b]:checked ~ input[name=c]:checked)~.items div[data-type=g] {
  display: block;
}
```

Now when two are checked we turn off visibility of the others:
Trick here is the `~.items :is([data-type])` finds the non-targeted siblings to turn those off.

THEN when three are checked we just show the ABC one.

```
input:is(input[name=a]:checked ~ input[name=b]:checked)~.items :is([data-type]),
input:is(input[name=a]:checked ~ input[name=c]:checked)~.items :is([data-type]),
input:is(input[name=b]:checked ~ input[name=c]:checked)~.items :is([data-type]),
input:is(input[name=a]:checked ~ input[name=b]:checked ~ input[name=c]:checked)~.items :is([data-type]) {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"]~label {
  padding-left: 1em;
}

input[type="checkbox"]~label::after {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
  margin-left: 3em;
}

.items>[data-type] {
  display: none;
}

input[name=a]:checked~.items div[data-type=a],
input[name=b]:checked~.items div[data-type=b],
input[name=c]:checked~.items div[data-type=c] {
  display: block;
}

input:is(input[name=a]:checked ~ input[name=b]:checked)~.items div[data-type=d],
input:is(input[name=a]:checked ~ input[name=c]:checked)~.items div[data-type=e],
input:is(input[name=b]:checked ~ input[name=c]:checked)~.items div[data-type=f],
input:is(input[name=a]:checked ~ input[name=b]:checked ~ input[name=c]:checked)~.items div[data-type=g] {
  display: block;
}

input:is(input[name=a]:checked ~ input[name=b]:checked)~.items :is([data-type]),
input:is(input[name=a]:checked ~ input[name=c]:checked)~.items :is([data-type]),
input:is(input[name=b]:checked ~ input[name=c]:checked)~.items :is([data-type]),
input:is(input[name=a]:checked ~ input[name=b]:checked ~ input[name=c]:checked)~.items :is([data-type]) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="a" name="a"><label for="a">A</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="b" name="b"><label for="b">B</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="c" name="c"><label for="c">C</label>
<div class="items">
  <div data-type="a">A</div>
  <div data-type="b">B</div>
  <div data-type="c">C</div>
  <div data-type="d">AB</div>
  <div data-type="e">AC</div>
  <div data-type="f">BC</div>
  <div data-type="g">ABC</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<label for="a">` will **never** be effective...

Comment: @MisterJojo - Yes, I did not put the ID on the input elements; a small thing here but noted for those clicking - I only put this in for the CSS formatting. I went ahead and added the IDs so that the labels are clickable also.  Alternate might be to wrap the inputs in the label and style the label as a block element rather than an inline one.